# T-SQL Restore DB with name Variables

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, variables, restore

I have to restore several database for a training class and am trying to create a script where I only have to change one variable. This is what I have but it won't work.

```
-- Declare the variable to be used.
DECLARE @DBVariable char;

-- Initialize the variable.
SET @DBVariable = '01';

USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [DBName] + @DBVariable  FROM  DISK = N'C:\Synergy Manual Backup\DBName.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'SLDemoSystem_Data' TO N'C:\MSSQL\DATA\DBName' + @DBVariable + '.mdf',  
MOVE N'SLDemoSystem_Log' TO N'C:\MSSQL\LOG\DBName' + @DBVariable + '.ldf',  
NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5

GO
```

Error messages are:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near '+'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: One thing I see off the bat is that you are declaring the length of your Char, so @DBVariable will always be = "0" you need to declare Char(2)

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near '+'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the the variables as below:

```
-- Declare the variable to be used.
DECLARE @DBVariable char(2);
-- Initialize the variable.
SET @DBVariable = '01';

USE [master]

DECLARE @DBNAME SYSNAME = 'DBName' + @DBVariable
DECLARE @DATA NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'C:\MSSQL\DATA\DBName' + @DBVariable + '.mdf'
DECLARE @LOG NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'C:\MSSQL\DATA\DBName' + @DBVariable + '.ldf'

RESTORE DATABASE @DBNAME
FROM  DISK = N'C:\Synergy Manual Backup\DBName.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'SLDemoSystem_Data' TO @DATA,  
MOVE N'SLDemoSystem_Log' TO @LOG,  
NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5

GO
```

Comment: I recommend this solution since it doesn't use EXEC

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic sql as string concat during backup/restore will not work with database name

```
-- Declare the variable to be used. -- Change it to 2 chars
DECLARE @DBVariable char(2);
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Initialize the variable.
SET @DBVariable = '01';

SET @SQL = 
N'RESTORE DATABASE [DBName' + @DBVariable '] FROM  DISK = N''C:\Synergy Manual Backup\DBName.bak'' WITH  FILE = 1,  
MOVE N''SLDemoSystem_Data'' TO N''C:\MSSQL\DATA\DBName' + @DBVariable + '.mdf'',  
MOVE N''SLDemoSystem_Log'' TO N''C:\MSSQL\LOG\DBName' + @DBVariable + '.ldf'',  
NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5'

USE [master]

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score -1):

Before to execute the backup example, please declare and set the variable values, my example is the following:

```
SELECT @SQL =   ' BACKUP DATABASE '+@bdName
SELECT @SQL +=  ' TO DISK = '''+@backUpPath+''''
SELECT @SQL +=  ' WITH FORMAT,  '
SELECT @SQL +=  ' MEDIANAME = '''+@bdName+''''
SELECT @SQL +=  ' ,NAME = '''+@bdName+''''
PRINT @SQL
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Restore example code that work for me, is the following:

```
SELECT @SQL =   ' RESTORE DATABASE '+@DEVbdName
SELECT @SQL =   ' FROM DISK = '''+@backUpPath+''''
SELECT @SQL =   ' WITH RECOVERY,'
SELECT @SQL =   ' MOVE '''+@bdName+''' TO '''+@DEVmdlFile+''''
SELECT @SQL =   ' ,MOVE '''+@DEVbdLogName+''' TO '+@DEVlogFile+'''';
EXEC (@SQL)
```